# Installing the docker desktop executable using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

I tried for Silent install of  docker desktop in windows using the PowerShell script.

Download link for the Docker.exe is "https://download.docker.com/win/stable/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe"

```
$updater = "C:\Check\Docker.exe"
(Start-Process "$updater" -ArgumentList ( "/S ")   -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
```

I am getting an error "Invalid operation: unkown command /S"

without any arguments we are getting the confirmation window for shortcut creation

Any argument passed is giving the Invalid Operation error.

Any Help.

Comment: -Arguments "install --quiet" helped me to proceed further but i am facing an error  [18:40:13.250] [InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.ShortcutAction
Deploying component: Add shortcut to desktop 100%
[18:40:13.359] [InstallWorkflow] Component CommunityInstaller.ShortcutAction failed
Exception type: System.IO.FileNotFoundException, Exception message: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax
 is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007B), StackTrace:.   How to uncheck the desktop shortcut creation option.